# How do I populate a combobox in a userform with each unique value from a range, sorted alphabetically?

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I'm going to be building a userform to be called by a macro in Excel 2013 to restore some values from a spreadsheet, and I need the comboboxes to populate based on the existing values. Populating by range is easy enough, that's working fine, but of course they're all jumbled up and frequently duplicated multiple times. In short, I'm getting this:

```
Charlie
Quebec
Echo
Zulu
Alpha
Quebec
```

...when what I want is:

```
Alpha
Charlie
Echo
Quebec
Zulu
```

I already have dynamic ranges set up for each of the source ranges.

What would be the most efficient way to handle it?

EDIT: More details.

The sets of data are held in the `"Saved Schedules"` sheet, each set to a row. At the moment I'm using the `Vessel Name` column (**C**). The idea is to select filters to narrow the list down, then select the specific voyage in `Voyage Code` up at the top of the form. (The yellow fields down the right preview the data so the operators see what they're about to load.) In essence, the basic data is in a sheet, filtered on the fly by the filter options in the userform, and the resulting voyage codes fed to the `Voyage Code` combobox for selection.

[image: Voyage restore form]

EDIT: I've tried Doug Coats' suggestions, edited as follows to apply to my form:

EDIT AGAIN: Corrected init sub name.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Me.Combo_Rest_VoyageCode.List = wsSaves.Range("SAVE_VoyageCode").Value  ' VOYAGE CODE
      Dim Ray, i As Integer, j As Integer, Temp As String
      With Combo_Rest_VoyageCode
           Ray = Application.Transpose(.List)
           For i = 1 To UBound(Ray) - 1
              For j = i To UBound(Ray)
                  If Ray(j) < Ray(i) Then
                       Temp = Ray(i)
                       Ray(i) = Ray(j)
                       Ray(j) = Temp
                  End If
              Next j
          Next i
      .List = Ray
      End With
End Sub
```

It doesn't meet with any more success, though. Is there anything there that doesn't apply to ActiveX comboboxes, perhaps?

Comment: Do you want to start from a set of cells, or from the current contents of the  combobox ??

Comment: It's to filter down the available source rows in a sheet to a manageable selection for the combobox - I'll clarify the details in the question for reference.

Answer (score 0):

a quick google search found tons of great information

you can alter this code to work with comboxes easily

here is a great link

http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/05/12/sorting-listboxes/

```
 Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
      Dim Ray, i As Integer, j As Integer, Temp As String
      With ListBox1
           Ray = Application.Transpose(.List)
           For i = 1 To UBound(Ray) - 1
              For j = i To UBound(Ray)
                  If Ray(j) < Ray(i) Then
                       Temp = Ray(i)
                       Ray(i) = Ray(j)
                       Ray(j) = Temp
                  End If
              Next j
          Next i
      .List = Ray
      End With
 End Sub
```

Comment: well i am working on getting it to work instead of posting a generic template, then ill work on duplicates

Comment: I fear you overestimate my knowledge - I've put that code in the form's `_Initialize`, edited it to fit my controls and sources, and the controls all remain resolutely empty. I'll put the edited code in the question so you can see what I mean.

Comment: I recently discovered that the best way to do this would be to sort contents before adding them with the ".AddItem" method, but this is of course assuming you put them in an array first. This topic is pretty much covered in depth in various other SO threads too.